# how to convert the string to hex code of the ASCII in C

Tags: c, string

I have a string like this "Hello"

Now I need to convert it to hex code of the ASCII code for each character so that I can insert it into the blob of database.

Can anybody offer any library function to convert the string?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply format characters to hexcode via [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char buf[255] = {0};
  char yourString[255] = { "Hello" };
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(yourString); i++) {
    sprintf(buf, "%s%x", buf, yourString[i]);
  }
  printf(buf+ '\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is great if all you want to do is have the very last character in your string converted to a hex character in a buffer

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby The answer was just written to illustrate that this library function can be used for this purpose. Please find the updated answer with complete code example that converts the complete string to hex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to convert the ascii string/char to a hex representation string.

**Very important**

if you want to have a correct conversion using the sprintf is to use unsigned char variables. Some char strings come in **unicode string format** and they need to be **first converted to `unsigned char`**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned char word[17], unsigned outword[33];//17:16+1, 33:16*2+1
    int i, len;

    printf("Intro word:");
    fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
    len = strlen(word);
    if(word[len-1]=='\n')
        word[--len] = '\0';

    for(i = 0; i<len; i++){
        sprintf(outword+i*2, "%02X", word[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", outword);
    return 0;
}
```