# In C, How to convert char* to hex

Tags: c, char, hex

I have extracted a MAC address into a `char*` array such that each section of the array is a pair of char values.

```
mac[0] = "a1"
mac[1] = "b2"
...
mac[5] = "f6"
```

Basically I need to take the char arrays and convert them to an unsigned char such that the hex representation is the same as the original char values.

```
a1 in ascii -> 0xa1
```

What is the best way to convert char* to hex in C?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586095/5842403

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My C isn't the best, but this works using strtol(start, [stop], base)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(char ** argv, int argc) {
  char * input = "a1";
  printf("%d\n", (unsigned char)strtol(input, NULL, 16));
}
```

Comment: @lnafziger AFAIK NULL is a define for 0, I just couldn't find it at first, was looking for null!

Comment: I probably should remove my answer, but in most `stdlib.h`, where `atoi` is defined, `NULL` is cast to a `char**`

Comment: @jordoex, `NULL` can be any null pointer constant, but I think usually it is `(void*)0`. In any case a plain old `0` would do also.

Comment: I'm just going with what's in most standard libraries, and so casting it will most likely prevent the compiler from issuing warnings.

Comment: `NULL` is not always defined the same way, but it does always equate to zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sscanf for this purpose.

```
int mac_byte;
unsigned char byte;
sscanf(mac[0],"%x",&mac_byte);
byte = mac_byte & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

---

```
unsigned char mac_uchar[6];

for(i = 0;i < 6; ++i) {
    mac_uchar = (unsigned char) strtol (&mac[n], (char **) NULL, 16);
}
```

I was slow in answering...