# How to convert string to hex value in C

Tags: c, string, hex

I have string "6A" how can I convert into hex value 6A?

Please help me with solution in C

I tried

```
char c[2]="6A"
char *p;
int x = atoi(c);//atoi is deprecated 

int y = strtod(c,&p);//Returns only first digit,rest it considers as string and
//returns 0 if first character is non digit char.
```

Comment: By using `val=strtol(string, NULL, 16);` It returns a `long` type so you might need to check/cast it.

Comment: Does not desrve downvote.Its genuine question.

Comment: @mah Hope that satisfies purpose now.

Comment: @SteveFenton Thanks,But I needed solution in C not obj-C.

Comment: I don't agree with the quick and overuse of downvotes, but the point to be made is when a quick search of `c convert string to hex` discloses the precise answer as the top return, it should have been used before turning to SO for help. SO is to help answer questions that haven't already been answered 1000 times over.

Comment: `char c[2]="6A"` is a problem.  should be `char c[]="6A"` or `char c[3]="6A"`.  `c` is not a _string_ unless it has a terminating null character.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586095/5842403

Comment: This title is misleading.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The question

> "How can I convert a string to a hex value?"

is often asked, but it's not quite the right question. Better would be

> "How can I convert a hex string to an integer value?"

The reason is, an integer (or char or long) value is stored in binary fashion in the computer.

```
"6A" = 01101010
```

It is only in human representation (in a character string) that a value is expressed in one notation or another

```
"01101010b"   binary
"0x6A"        hexadecimal
"106"         decimal
"'j'"         character
```

all represent the same value in different ways.

But in answer to the question, how to convert a hex string to an `int`

```
char hex[] = "6A";                          // here is the hex string
int num = (int)strtol(hex, NULL, 16);       // number base 16
printf("%c\n", num);                        // print it as a char
printf("%d\n", num);                        // print it as decimal
printf("%X\n", num);                        // print it back as hex
```

Output:

```
j
106
6A
```