# Read hex from standard input in c

Tags: c, hex, stdin

I am trying to read a hexadecimal input from stdin in c. The input is already in a hexadecimal format, for example, a input can look like this 616263. I want to read it from stdin and interpret it as unsigned long int msg = 0x616263;

I understand that stdin only reads ascii chars but is there a way to interpret it as hexadecimal values?

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547115/how-to-convert-string-to-hex-value-in-c

Comment: You can use the `scanf()` family of functions and `"%lx"`, as one option.

Answer (score 2):

use strtoul with base 16
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/

```
char temp[] = "616263";

number = strtoul(temp,0,16);
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the string, interpret with [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html)

```
char datafromstdin[] = "616263";
int x = strtol(datafromstdin, NULL, 16);
```

The code needs error checking.