# directly cast a char *nib as int hex

Tags: c, casting, binary, hex

in pure and portable c.

So I am having trouble casting what has to be a variable, from a variable.  char *nib to int hex.  The idea being I had a char *nib ="ab"; or "0xab" or anything that directly represents two characters as a char *.  then casting it as a integer.  and writing it to a file to get a one to one write.  so I start with char *nib="0xab"; then I write it as a int presumably, and to a hexdump or edit and the result is just ab.

I've been able to do this as a constant directly declaring... but the nib is always static.

this has to be a one to one starting with a two char string or nib.  Not converting anything,  purly casting.

So can you write it directly to a file without converting it? three look up tables seems like a bit much for a value what has the name length

Comment: You can't cast the text representing the number to the number. You need to convert it for example using atoi function

Comment: Unrelated to what you're actually asking, but why is it called `nib`? A nibble is half a byte (4 bits), but `ab` or `0xab` is the hex representation of 1 byte (8 bits).

Comment: @P__J__ sounds like OP actually does not need to start from readable string - " or anything that directly represents two characters as a `char *`"... maybe "\x0a\x0b" is what they are starting with? (still not enough for `int` and unlikely portable when stored to file... but better than "ab")

Comment: bit is half a byte? nyb is half a bit?

Comment: @mistermista A byte is 8 bits (on most architectures, there are some other ones). A nibble is half a byte.

Comment: (Side note: @mistermista  please read info of the tags before using them - "nib" you've added as tag to this post has nothing to do with bytes and rather OSX file format - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nib/info)

Comment: yeah its not that I don't believe you that conerting it is th eonly way, but maybe you could illustrate your example of writiba "ab" with atoi to get hexdump to return ab.

Comment: Just write the bytes individually with `putchar`.  You don't need to convert both characters to a single combined integer value.

Comment: @mistermista There's a difference between the character `'a'`, which is equivalent to the integer value `97` in ASCII encoding for example, and the hex value `a` which is `10` in base 10. That's why you can't just use a cast.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way  to cast 2 characters (2 bytes) into one byte because cast does not change binary representation of the value.

The closest you can get to casting string that looks like hex to some value that will show something similar is use 0-15 characters via escape sequence like `char*  nib = "\x0A\x0B"` and cast ( `*((short*)nib)`) that to 2-byte value (`0x0A0B` in this case) and store that to a file (I'm not sure if there is *portable* integer type of 2 bytes - `short` often is 2 bytes wide  but does not have to be 2 bytes). Unfortunately I don't think there is a portable way to store 2 byte integer value to a file as different architectures may have different byte order.

Writing string value character by character is likely safest approach. Or convert string to `int` a [usual way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547115/how-to-convert-string-to-hex-value-in-c) and use your own read/write code for integers to ensure portability.