# How to extract values from a string in hexadecimal in a C program?

Tags: c

I have a hexadecimal string like:

```
char str[] = "40004A0060007A0034006600";
```

I want to extract individual values from it like 0x40, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x00 etc.

How to do it?

Comment: Look into `strtol` and then particularly the 3rd argument to make it base 16.

Comment: Are you at least somewhat familiar with strings?

Comment: Using [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547115/how-to-convert-string-to-hex-value-in-c/29547549) and some very basic string manipulations will do the job. 6-7 lines of code.

Comment: We can't tell you why your attempt isn't working if you don't show it to us.

Comment: Don't change the question completely once there are answers posted! If you have a different question, then ask a new one. "Moving goal posts" questions tend to be very poorly received. I did a rollback of all content changes.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Note that in your edit of the question, in which you shortened the string to 10 digits, you substantially changed the question, by making another solution viable. After this part of your edit was reverted by OP, my answer was therefore partially invalidated. I don't want to criticize your good work, but I do want to point out that this seems to have triggered (or at least contibuted to) an edit war. :-)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you are right, and your criticism is constructive and OK. I shouldn't have shortened so much. I edited so the question is as close as possible to the OP's question.

Comment: You completely changed the question and you also mentioned `sprintf` in one of your edits. Please consider the answers below and ask a separate question dealing with the sprint issue.

Answer (score 2):

- Copy the 2 bytes of interest into a temporary 3 byte array.
- Null terminate the 3 byte array to turn it into a string.
- Call `strtoul` on this array from stdlib.h.

Alternatively you could manually decode it, since it's a trivial thing to do. Mask out nibbles, subtract some ASCII values or do a lookup table check, then multiply the ms nibble by 16.

Comment: In this case the "manual" way seem to be even easier and more efficient.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah. What's easiest depends on programmer competence. Someone who has passed an introductory C programming class at university will easily be able to code the manual version. But such a person wouldn't have to ask this question either...

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE: This answer applies to [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69451263/3) of the question. Meanwhile, the question has been modified, thereby invalidating option #1 of my answer. As pointed out in the comments section of the question, this was not OP's fault, though.**

You have two options:

1. Convert the string to an integer type, for example using the function [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) or `strtoull`, and then use bit-shifting (`>>` operator) and bit-masking (`&` operator) to obtain the desired values. However, due to limitations in the range of values that the data types `long` and `long long` can represent, this option is only guaranteed to work with up to 8 hexadecimal digits with `strtoul` and 16 digits with `strtoull`. EDIT: Meanwhile, the question has been modified in such a way that the string is longer than 16 digits, so this solution is no longer viable.
2. Obtain the desired values by looking them up directly in the string. For example, if you are looking for the 3<sup>rd</sup> group of hexadecimal digits, then you will find them using `str[4]` and `str[5]`. This will give you two character values. If you want to convert these two hexadecimal characters to the number that they represent, then you can create a string from these two values and then use `strtoul` on that string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be a beginner, I broke the task up into its constituent parts. This is a very simple hex dump facility where each step your code needs to take is its own routine. It is a quick and dirty and rather imperfect implementation, but understanding how to improve it will help you learn and write your own.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
nibble(uint8_t ch) {
    if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) {
        return ch - '0';
    }

    if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'F')) {
        return 10 + (ch - 'A');
    }

    if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'f')) {
        return 10 + (ch - 'a');
    }

    /* should never get here if isxdigit was called first */
    return -1;
}

int
next_byte(const char *in)
{

    uint8_t hi = 16 * nibble(*in);
    uint8_t lo = nibble(*(in + 1));

    return hi + lo;
}

int points_to_byte(const char *in) {
    return ((*in) && isxdigit(*in))
        && (*(in + 1)) && isxdigit(*(in + 1));
}

void
dump(const char *in) {
    /* Decide what to do with input that is not a string of hex bytes */
    for (int i = 0; points_to_byte(in + i); i += 2) {
        printf("%d\n", next_byte(in + i));
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        puts("Need hex strings as arguments");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        dump(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

When compile this into an executable called `t` and run it with your input, this is the output I get:

```
$ ./t 400004a005b002000113efb29f73f57589343e70e5244162edf312e303030322e313420200043472d58585858000000000032303139303833585858585858000000505230474C5043343554334C3343
64 
0  
4  
160
...
67 
52 
195
52
```

> want to convert it into a other string like

> ```
>  char str1[] ="0x40,0x00,0x4A,0x00,0x60";
> ```

Since you do not control the input string, you are going to need to `malloc` the buffer for the output. That and storing the transformed output is left as an exercise.

Comment: Note that this solution will only work with character sets in which the letters are stored consecutively, such as ASCII. It won't work for example on [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). The ISO C standard only guarantees that the characters `'0'` to `'9'` are stored consecutively, but not `'A'` to `'Z'`, or `'a'` to `'z'`. However, it is probably rather safe to assume that OP is using an ASCII-compatible character set.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Of course. That is one of the things the OP might or might not get extra credit for mentioning or rectifying in the homework if this indeed is homework.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that my previous comment was not quite correct. Your solution will also work on EBCDIC, because the characters `'A'` to `'I'` are stored consecutively. You only need the characters `'A'` to `'F'` to be stored consecutively, not all of the characters from '`A'` to `'Z'`. Therefore, EBCDIC was a bad example. However, there may be some character sets in use in which `'A'` to `'F'` are not stored consecutively (I don't know of any, though).