# How to produce an executable file out of binary?

Tags: c, binary, compiler-construction, machine-code

Writing a compiler here into native machine code, and I learnt pretty much everything I need from how to parse source code to get its respective assembly and machine code sequence of zeros and ones. The only thing that I do not understand is how I write the result into a file in such way that it was not a text file but an executable instead. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547115/how-to-convert-string-to-hex-value-in-c) it seems that it's enough to just pass raw integer, so if I have

```c
//The binary sequence of zeroes and ones.
int binaryBuffer[200]; 
FILE* result = fopen("result", "w");
fwrite(binaryBuffer, 1, 1
    /*size of a byte*/, result);
fclose(result);
```

Will this code write machine code executable file given that `binaryBuffet` is the array of integer zeroes and ones? Do I need just to store the machine code as a long integer in the memory and then pass it into the `fwrite()`?

Comment: First you need to learn the executable format for your target platform. This is no easy task, might even be harder then writing the compiler itself. Then you have to remember that executable files are ***b**inary* files, not text files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude exactly! So how can I cast textual representation of the machine code itself or hexadecimal into this binary format?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `executable files are binary files, not text files.` I would not say that. Executable files contain binary code and much, much more. One way to think of executable files is as the input to a [loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)). See: [Comparison of executable file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats). Continued.

Comment: What the OP needs to understand is how to convert the binary into an [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) and then use a [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) to create the executable.

Comment: @GuyCoder You can't write raw binary data when you open the file in text-mode, like in `fopen(..., "w")`. The open-mode needs to be `"wb"`. Well, *can't*  is maybe a bit strong, but remember that on some platforms certain "characters" (bytes) will be *translated* when reading from or writing to a file opened in text-mode (without the `b` in the open-mode).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't know where you are going with that reply but it is disconnected from what I stated.

Comment: @GuyCoder Regarding the executable files are binary file part. Note that the OP opens the file on *text* mode. Writing object file or executable files needs to be done in binary mode.

Comment: To the OP: Regarding the writing of the data, writing only a single byte won't work very well if your binary data is larger than one byte.